# Prevent iOS from NOT using my custom keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

iOS sometimes chooses to use the OS's keyboard even though I've disabled all keyboards but my 3rd party keyboard. For example when trying to log into a financial app.

My custom keyboard has accessibility features not available in the iOS keyboards so when it forces the OS keyboard it makes it harder for me to use my phone.

I understand why it does this (Apple believes it's more secure) but I trust my keyboard. I wouldn't be using it otherwise. I use that keyboard all over the OS including logging into financial websites. In other words, this feature is a nanny feature and I want it off.

Is it possible for get iOS to not force its keyboard on me?

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Apple does this for a reason. You may trust YOUR keyboard. But does that you trust any keyboard that now has this ability to force itself to be your keyboard for sensitive data fields?